# Equation Given : x = (((x+8)/3)%5)*5; solve the above equation using assignment operators (eg. +=, -=, *=)

Tags: c++

Equation Given :

```
x = (((x+8)/3)%5)*5;
```

solve the above equation using *assignment operator*s (eg. `+=`, `-=`, `*=`).

Can someone help with this c++ problem? 
sorry if this a dumb question

Comment: Start from the innermost expression and work outwards.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can convert a single readable formula

```
 x = (((x + 8) / 3) % 5) * 5;
```

into *four* ones:

```
 x += 8;
 x /= 3;
 x %= 5;
 x *= 5;
```